# Are the sympathetic and parasympathetic nervous systems exact opposites?

Tags: autonomic-nervous-system

Suppose mechanism existed that could block function of the PNS. Would this just mean then the sympathetic nervous system would become overly active?

Do the sympathetic and parasympathetic systems act as opposing forces?

Answer (score 1):

The Autonomic Nervous System is composed of the sympathetic and parasympathetic nervous systems. Each are dominant under different conditions - both are always active but one is **dominant**.

An important way to understand the the autonomic nervous system is in considering the effects of pharmaceutical drugs.

**Sympathomimetic** drugs enhance adrenergic function.
**Sympatholytic** drugs interrupt adrenergic function.

**Parasympathomimetic** drugs enhance cholinergic effects.
**Anticholinergic** drugs inhibit cholinergic effects.

For example:

Muscarinic antagonists are [parasympatholytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasympatholytic) (Anticholinergic) drugs - which reduce the effects of parasympathetic system.

But it is not that simple. **They also increase sympathetic tone**.

But again it is not always that simple. E.g. for sympathomimetic drugs (enhance adrenergic function) - there is **no** parasympathetic nervous system effect.

To answer your question, the sympathetic and parasympathetic nervous systems oppose each other *sometimes*. **It depends on which receptors are activated and where**.

(E.g.Alpha 1 receptors, Alpha 2 receptors, Beta 1 receptors & Beta 2 receptors).

[Source & further reading on pharmaceutical interventions](https://opentextbc.ca/anatomyandphysiology/chapter/15-4-drugs-that-affect-the-autonomic-system/)

[Source & further reading on receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenergic_receptor)